# Modificar elemento através do JavaScript e "avisar" a página que o elemento foi modificado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myTextarea").change(function(){
    alert("text area changed");
  });
  
  //$("#myTextarea").keydown(function(){
    //alert("text area changed");
  //});
});
 
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#myTextarea").val("changed");
  $("#myTextarea").blur();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <textarea id="myTextarea" rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Eu preciso saber porque o código acima não funciona, na teoria, o `textarea` ao ser modificado dentro do `setTimeout`, deveria executar o código da função `change`, mas não executa e preciso saber porque e como resolvo isso.

Comment: Você está dizendo na hora de apertar alguma tecla?

Comment: Não necessariamente @VirgilioNovic, se você executar o exemplo acima você verá que eu modifico o elemento pelo JS, mas a página não entende que ele foi modificado e o código do evento `change`, não é executado.

Comment: Fabiano, seu eu alterar e sair da caixa ele realiza o que precisa, "acho eu" não está claro o que é pra fazer? o que é para fazer esse código?

Comment: Exato @VirgilioNovic, se você **manualmente** digitar algo no textarea e sair do elemento, o código que eu quero que seja executado será rodado, **mas** o meu problema é que eu preciso alterar o elemento **através do javascript** e preciso que o evento seja chamado quando eu alterá-lo **via javascript**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispara uma trigger ao invés do blur()...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myTextarea").change(function(){
    alert("text area changed");
  });
  
  //$("#myTextarea").keydown(function(){
    //alert("text area changed");
  //});
});
 
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#myTextarea").val("changed");
  //$("#myTextarea").blur();
  $("#myTextarea").trigger("change");
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <textarea id="myTextarea" rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Certo Julio, isso possivelmente resolve o meu problema e eu entendo porque funciona, mas você concorda que: se eu comentar a linha `$("#myTextarea").val("changed");`o evento vai ser disparado do mesmo jeito, mesmo sem o elemento de fato ter sido modificado? Eu queria algo que inteligentemente fizesse com que o navegador reconhecesse que o elemento foi de fato modificado.

Comment: @FabianoLothor trabalhe com angularJs então!

Comment: Nesse caso em específico não dá @VirgilioNovic, estou criando um script para ser executado sempre que eu acessar uma página específica (que não é minha) e nessa página, quando eu digito algo no `textarea` ela faz algo, eu queria que sempre que eu abrisse a página o evento fosse executado automaticamente, estranhamente lá, nem usando `trigger` a ação é executada, provavelmente o `listener` não é para o evento `change` e eu não sei qual é. :/

Answer (score 0):

Logo após a alteração no textarea use o método [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), e chame o evento que precisa no caso `change`, exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myTextarea").change(function(){
    alert("text area changed");
  });
});
 
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#myTextarea").val("changed").trigger('change');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<textarea id="myTextarea" rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [jQuery - .trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)
- [Triggering Event Handlers](https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/)

Answer (score 0):

Esse evento só é disparado quando o usuário altera o conteúdo da `textarea`e o elemento perde o foco (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/change).

Você pode disparar o evento utilizando `jquery`da seguinte forma:

`$("#myTextarea").change();` (https://api.jquery.com/change/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myTextarea").change(function(){
    alert("text area changed");
  });
  
  //$("#myTextarea").keydown(function(){
    //alert("text area changed");
  //});
});
 
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#myTextarea").val("changed");
  $("#myTextarea").change();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <textarea id="myTextarea" rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```